# How to install Sharepoint CALs?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing, cal

If my company has a SPLA license with access to Sharepoint 2013 media\install key available how do you go about purchasing\installing user CALs?  I'm coming from my experience with Terminal Servers \ RD Session Hosts where you must install a license server\activate\install per user CALs.  Does the equivalent not exist in Sharepoint?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from the Microsoft Volume Licensing Center.

You need to get a quote on how many CALs you need [here](http://mla.microsoft.com/default.aspx) and refer to this page: http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/ProductPage.aspx?pid=457

Once you have the number of CALs you need for SharePoint, then contact a licensing agent/partner to Microsoft [here](https://pinpoint.microsoft.com/search?type=companies&competency=100010&businessNeed=200168&page=0):

In short, there are licenses for SharePoint that state one license yields a certain number of SharePoint servers, then there are Standard CALs and Enterprise CALs that are per user. This is a good read: [Licensing for SharePoint 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/briefs/SharepointServer2013.aspx)

Comment: Just to add to Mike's answer, you do not install CALs like you would in terminal server. User access is pretty much on the honor system compared to TS where once your CALs are used up by existing connections, no one else can connect.

Comment: Thank you both! I had a hunch this was the case, but wanted to be sure before diving in.